# What is the meaning of "Y is a function of X"?

Tags: terminology

Based on my life experience I assume that with "daily life language", when people say "Y is a function of X", the meaning could be:

1. Y is a potential mode, given X
2. Y is a practical mode, given X
3. There is no guarantee for either and the meaning could be either 1 or 2 (which encapsulates 1, because every practice is potential but not every potentiality is practical)

**What is the meaning of "Y is a function of X" (at least in formal-logic context)?**

Comment: Questions about the meaning of colloquial expressions are off-topic on this site, they are better suited for [English SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Conifold I do want a formal-logic oriented answer; the colloquial meaning is not my primary concern here; perhaps I should edit o clarify that.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the contributor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)):

> In mathematics, a *function* is a relation between two sets that associates every element of the first set to exactly one element of the second set.

> Functions were originally the idealization of how a varying quantity depends on another quantity. For example, the position of a planet is a function of time.

Thus, in general, to say that "Y is a function of X" means that a certain variable magnitude or phenomenon Y is determined/caused by another magnitude or phenomenon X, such that the behavior of X will affect that of Y.

---

In logic, a [function symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_predicate)

> is a logical symbol that may be applied to an object term to produce another object term.

An example of "logical function" is: "father of..."; for every human as input, the function will output the father of the previous one.

Comment: I thank you for the great answer; I understand that simply put, a mathematical function "translated" to colloquial language with "Y is a function of X" means that **practically** Y is a function of X.